# How to start/stop/restart jQuery animation

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I have the following function that when I call displays a message to the user for a certain amount of time (5 secs in my case). During this "period" if I call the function again to display another message, practically it should hide, then re-appear with the new message for another 5 seconds.

What happens with my code below, I call the function to display the message. Then, lets say on the 4th second, I call it again to display another message, the new message is displayed for 1 second.

I need to somehow -reset- the time but can't figure out how. Tried stopping the animation, checking if the element was visible and hiding it if it was, and many other things. I believe the solution is a simple chaining issue but can't get it right. So any help would be appreciated!

```
function display_message(msgType, message) {

    var elem = $('#ur_messagebox');

    switch (msgType) {
        case 'confirm':
            elem.addClass('msg_confirm');
            break;

        case 'error':
            elem.addClass('msg_error');
            break;
    }

    elem.html(message);
    elem.show().delay(5000).fadeOut(1000);
}
```

thanks in advance...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In short, you can't use [`.delay()`](http://api.jquery.com/delay/) for what you want.  It's just a wrapper for [`setTimeout()`](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp) on the next queue item, [you can see the source here](http://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/queue.js#L75), the important part:

```
    return this.queue( type, function() {
        var elem = this;
        setTimeout(function() {
            jQuery.dequeue( elem, type );
        }, time );
    });
```

So this is just queuing a `setTimeout()` which when executed, dequeues the next item in the queue and executes it.  So what is happening is you've added a delay, and even with [`.stop(true)`](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) or [`.clearQueue()`](http://api.jquery.com/clearQueue/), when you queue the [`.fadeOut()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/) afterwards you're adding that back to the **same** `fx` queue, so when that `setTimeout()` finishes in 5 seconds, it's grabbing the **new** fade you queued and executing it.

You'll need to `setTimout()` and clear it manually, since jQuery core doesn't have this built-in, something like this:

```
function display_message(msgType, message) {
  var mb = $('#ur_messagebox')
           .addClass(msgType === 'confirm' ? 'msg_confirm' : 'msg_error')
           .html(message)
           .stop(true, true).fadeIn();
  if(mb.data('delay')) clearTimeout(mb.data('delay'));
  mb.data('delay', setTimeout(function() { mb.fadeOut(1000); }, 5000));
}
```

[You can see a working demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/fyzNn/)

Answer (score 1):

As [Nick](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2892032/490560) pointed out:

> In short, you can't use .delay() for what you want.

But there is a simple workaround: instead of using `.delay(x)` just use `.fadeTo(x,1)`.

Basically, this would fade to full opacity, but since the message box is already at full opacity, this does nothing except delaying the following animations for `x` milliseconds. And the advantage is that `.fadeTo()` can be stopped/aborted using `.stop(true)`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
elem.stop().show().delay(5000).fadeOut(1000);
```

Comment: thıs does not work. tried it before. the new message is displayed but for a period of whatever left from that 5 seconds of the first message.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting CSS conflicts because you never remove the msg classes before adding the other, so I cleared those with `elem.removeClass('msg_confirm msg_error');` in addition to fixing the problem:

```
function display_message(msgType, message) {

    var elem = $('#ur_messagebox');
    elem.removeClass('msg_confirm msg_error');

    switch (msgType) {
        case 'confirm':
            elem.addClass('msg_confirm');
            break;

        case 'error':
            elem.addClass('msg_error');
            break;
    }

    elem.stop().css({opacity:1}).clearQueue();
    elem.html(message);
    elem.show().delay(5000).fadeOut(1000);
}
```

So with `elem.stop().css({opacity:1}).clearQueue();` I stop the animation, reset the opacity in case it was in the middle of fading out and clear the queue before adding the message and restarting the queue.  I tested this and it should work for you.

Comment: nope! this also doesn't seem to work. the more I delve into this, the more I come accross more people having problems with the delay function. read the comments here http://api.jquery.com/delay/

Comment: Ah, interesting, I only tested certain cases but it doesn't work for all.  Will keep fiddling.

Answer (score 0):

I restart animations this way: (not sure if it's entirely right, though)

$(element).stop().clearQueue();

$(element).delay(20).animate({ ... });

Answer (score 0):

if using jQuery, just finish the current animation before restarting it again:

```
tooltip.finish();// set a defined start for animation
tooltip.show();
tooltip.delay(4000).fadeOut(1500);
```